# Trouble With Generics and Static Inner Classes

Tags: java, generics

So I have a class that uses an  generic:

```
public class Deque<Item> implements Iterable<Item>
```

Inside that class I have a static inner class that also uses the same  generic:

```
public static class Node<Item> {
        Node next; // pointer to next node
        Node prev; // pointer to previous node 
        Item data; // data contained in node

        public Node(Item item){
            this.data = item;
        }
    }
```

Trouble is, when I try to assign information from the `data` variable within the inner variable, which is declared with the Item generic, to a variable declared with the Item generic in the main class, like so:

```
Item data = oldNode.data;
```

I get the following error:

```
type mismatch: cannot convert Object to Item.
```

Thoughts?

Comment: what is oldNode here, provide full code,,then only its easy to debug. Thanks

Comment: Both `next` and `prev` are missing the generic type and should be declared `Node<Item>`.

Comment: FYI, You're declaring these classes *like* they were generics ... but then not using generics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How have you declared oldNode ?

Look at this method :

```
private void foo(Item item) {
    Node<Item> oldNode = new Node<Item>(item); // declaration using generics.
    Item data = oldNode.data; // compiles fine

    Node oldNode2 = new Node(item); // un-generic declaration. Compiler doesn't know if it's node a Node of something else.
    Item data = oldNode2.data; // compile error: type mismatch: cannot convert Object to item.
}
```

You have to declare oldNode as a `Node<Item>` so the compiler knows in subsequent code that oldNode.data is of type Item.